# Python web scraping specific information

Tags: python, html, scripting, functional-programming

I am trying to pull some information from a webpage and format it. I can pull the data but the format is broken. I want to end up with one line that looks like the one below:

MAC Address,F41FC267FC1D,Host Name,SEPF41FC267FC1D,Phone DN,28292, App Load ID,jar45sccp.9-3-1ES13.sbn,Boot Load ID,tnp45.9-3-1-CR17.bin,Version,*SCCP45.9-3-1SR2-1S*,Hardware Revision,13.0, Serial Number,FCH17188DSC, Model Number,CP-7945G, Message Waiting,Yes, UDI,phone,Cisco Unified IP Phone 7945G,Global,Gig Ethernet,Color,CP-7945G,V14,FCH17188DSC, Time,10:40:10a,Time Zone,EST5EDT,Date,02/10/16,System Free Memory,4346528, Java Heap Free Memory,2502292, Java Pool Free Memory

Webpage with information:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><TITLE>Cisco Systems, Inc.</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF" text="#003031"><TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" bordercolor="#003031"><TR>
<td WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="100" ALIGN=center><A HREF="http://www.cisco.com"><IMG SRC="/FS/Logo.png"></A></TD><td HEIGHT="50" bgcolor="#003031"><p ALIGN=center><B><font color="#FFFFFF" size="6">Device Information</FONT></B><p ALIGN=center><B><font color="#FFFFFF" size="4">Cisco Unified IP Phone CP-7945G ( SEPF41FC267FC1D )</FONT></FONT></B></TD>
</TR>
<TR><td WIDTH="200" ALIGN=center VALIGN=top bgcolor="#003031"><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10" CELLPADDING="0"><TR>
<TD><a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.device">Device Information</A></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.configuration">Network Configuration</A></TD></TR>
<TR><TD><B><font color='#FFFFFF'>Network Statistics</FONT></B></TD></TR><TR>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.ethernet">Ethernet Information</A></TD>
</TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.port.access">Access</A></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.port.network">Network</A></TD></TR><TR><TD><B><font color='#FFFFFF'>Device Logs</FONT></B></TD></TR><TR>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.consolelog">Console Logs</A></TD><TR>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.coredumps">Core Dumps</A></TD><TR>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.settings.status.messages">Status Messages</A></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.trace.display.alarm">Debug Display</A></TD></TR>
<TR><TD><B><font color='#FFFFFF'>Streaming Statistics</FONT></B></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.streaming.0">Stream 1 </A></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.streaming.1">Stream 2 </A></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.streaming.2">Stream 3 </A></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.streaming.3">Stream 4 </A></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/CGI/Java/Serviceability?adapter=device.statistics.streaming.4">Stream 5 </A></TD></TR></TABLE>
</TD>
<td VALIGN=top><DIV ALIGN=center>
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="10" CELLPADDING="0"><TR><TD><B> MAC Address</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>F41FC267FC1D</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Host Name</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>SEPF41FC267FC1D</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Phone DN</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>28292</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> App Load ID</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>jar45sccp.9-3-1ES13.sbn</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Boot Load ID</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>tnp45.9-3-1-CR17.bin</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Version</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>*SCCP45.9-3-1SR2-1S*</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Hardware Revision</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>13.0</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Serial Number</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>FCH17188DSC</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Model Number</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>CP-7945G</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Message Waiting</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>Yes</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> UDI</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>phone</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> </B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>Cisco Unified IP Phone 7945G, Global, Gig Ethernet, Color</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> </B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>CP-7945G</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> </B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>V14</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> </B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>FCH17188DSC</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Time</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>10:49:52a</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Time Zone</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>EST5EDT</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Date</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>02/10/16</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> System Free Memory</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>4346528</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Java Heap Free Memory</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>2502060</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> Java Pool Free Memory</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>107608</B></TD></TR><TR><TD><B> FIPS Mode Enabled</B></TD><td width=20></TD><TD><B>No</B></TD></TR></TABLE></DIV></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

Python Code:

```
      import urllib
      import urllib.request
      from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
      import os

      def make_soup(url):
      thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
      soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
      return soupdata


      phonedatasaved=" "
      soup = make_soup("http://phone/")
      for div in soup.findAll("div"):

      phonedata=" "
      for tr in div.findAll('tr'):
      for td in tr.findAll('td'):
        phonedata=phonedata+","+td.text
        phonedatasaved = phonedatasaved + "\n" + phonedata[0:]
        print(phonedatasaved)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need functions. This should do:

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')
elements =soup('table')[-1]('b')
lst = []
for i in range(0, len(elements), 2):
    lst.append(elements[i].text.strip())
    lst.append(elements[i+1].text.strip())
print ', '.join(lst)
```

Edit: What is not right in your code? My thoughts:

1. It's not the right practice trying to print out the added string in a loop.
2. What is the code trying to do with `phonedata[0:]`? Actually, `phonedata[0:] = phonedata`.
3. Variables like 'phonedatasaved', 'phonedata' are not needed.
4. The code does not need to print it out if td.text is empty.

Overall, the implementation in your code is very confusing to me. Here is a modified version:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("http://phone/")

for div in soup.findAll("div"):
    for tr in div.findAll('tr'):
        for td in tr.findAll('td'):
            if td.text.strip():
                print(td.text.strip()) + ',',
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. I am new at python. I want to stick to my code so I can learn what I am doing wrong. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @user1819884: your code is not properly formatted, can you please fix that?

Comment: I just ran your code but the formatting is not exactly what I need. how can I change the format of your code to show the output as a single line comma delimited.